# Delete login data from database when timestamp expires MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this database:

```
login_id -> AI, INT, PK
login_token -> VARCHAR(255)
login_userId -> VARCHAR(255)
login_expires -> VARCHAR(255)
```

`login_expires` is a UNIX timestamp.

The `login_token` will be bound to a cookie. When the cookie expires, the row from the database with the `login_token` from the cookie should be deleted too.

What's the easiest why to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MySQL >= 5.1 you can use an event scheduler:

```
CREATE EVENT expired
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTES
DO
   DELETE FROM your_table
   WHERE login_expires < NOW();
```

Read more about this in [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is it!